# creating JSON with jQuery from inputs after save btn click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have simple for you problem with creating JSON using jQuery.

I have an admin panel which is based on JSON data. I have allready put all JSON variables into inputs (they are showing). Now I need to save them back to a new JSON (must be new) and export it to php API. I have tried everything, and read alot of stack topics, but I didnt find answer.

Here is my problem

some part of JSON Structure:

```
"sayTextColor": "0xFF000000",
 "sayFrameColor": "0xFF000000",
 "sayRandom": "true",
 "sayCount": "6",
 "sayC": [
   {
     "active": "true",
     "text": "Work hard, play hard!",
     "iconId": "43"
   },
   {
     "active": "false",
     "text": "Work hard, play hard2!",
     "iconId": "44"
   }
 ],
 "thinkTextColor": "0xFF000000",
 "thinkFrameColor": "0xFF000000",
 "thinkC": [
   {
     "active": "false",
     "text": "I'll be back"
   },
   {
     "active": "false",
     "text": "I'll be back2"
   }
 ]
}
```

...etc

I am using elements generated with JSON and those added after using admin pannel.

SAMPLE:

```
<div class="say-item c">

        <div class="c-img"></div>

        <h4>Head text</h4>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <div class="delete-btn"></div>
        <div class="activate">
            <div class="squaredchb">
                <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="activate-c" name="check"  />
                <label for="activate-c"></label>
                <p>use this element</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="preview-btn">
            <img src="images/preview_icon.png" alt="" />
            <span>Preview</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I create JSON from this - now I am so confused that I don't know how to create new Object correctly.

I asking You to help with building object with variables changing after click save btn.

ie. `{"some string key", variableFromInput }` using `$.each` for different JSON level.

Thanks
Fantazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is `JSON.stringify()`.
Which you can use to generate json string from your input and do whatever you want with it.

It's a little bit messy example, but I'm working :)

```js
 (function() {
   $('#createJson').on('click', function() {
     var all_says = [];
     $('.say-item').each(function(key, value) {
       var text = $(this).find('textarea').val();
       var active = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
       var obj = {
         text: text,
         active: active
       };
       all_says.push(obj);
     })
     $('#gen').val(JSON.stringify(all_says));
   });
 })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="say-item cloud">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="activate-a" name="check" />
</div> 
   <div class="say-item cloud">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="activate-b" name="check" />
</div>
<div class="say-item cloud">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="activate-c" name="check" />
</div>

<h2>Generated Json</h2>
<textarea id="gen"></textarea>
<button id="createJson">Create JSON</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for =) Regards, Fantazy!